# Eclipse, regular expression search and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

In eclipse, is it possible to use the matched search string as part of the replace string when performing a regular expression search and replace?

Basically, I want to replace all occurrences of

```
variableName.someMethod()
```

with:

```
((TypeName)variableName.someMethod())
```

Where `variableName` can be any variable name at all.

In *sed* I could use something like:

```
s/[a-zA-Z]+\.someMethod\(\)/((TypeName)&)/g
```

That is, `&` represents the matched search string. Is there something similar in Eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: Good documentation on Eclipse RegEx: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Fnode4.html

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Yes, `(` `)` captures a group. You can use it again with `$i` where `i` is the i'th capture group.

So:

> search: `(\w+\.someMethod\(\))`
>
> replace: `((TypeName)$1)`

Hint: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> in the textboxes gives you all kinds of suggestions for regular expression writing.

Comment: That's a nice answer and a useful hint. It would have been more helpful had it been described in little more detail.

Comment: Bravo Eclipse, you implemented this feature properly!

Comment: I especially love the example for "Hex code for Unicode character" :)

Comment: I would like to add some code that really helped me. I needed to replace every `stringVar.equals("xxx")` with `"xxx".equals(stringVar)`. I used the following regex in the find/replace dialog: `search: ([^()! ]+).equals\("(.*)"\)`, `replace: "$2".equals\($1\)`.

Comment: Not for me. Always replaces the first group...?

Comment: do you know if it is possible to use transform options in replace to make upper or lower replaces?

hypothetical example: 
replace: ((TypeName)TOUPPER($1))

Answer (score 8):

Using ... 

search  = (^.*import )(.*)(\(.*\):) 

replace = $1$2

...replaces ...

```
from checks import checklist(_list):
```

...with...

```
from checks import checklist
```

Blocks in regex are delineated by parenthesis (which are not preceded by a "\")

(^.*import ) finds "from checks import " and loads it to $1 (eclipse starts counting at 1)

(.*) find the next "everything" until the next encountered "(" and loads it to $2. $2 stops at the "(" because of the next part (see next line below)

(\(.*\):) says "at the first encountered "(" after starting block $2...stop block $2 and start $3. $3 gets loaded with the "('any text'):" or, in the example, the "(_list):" 

Then in the replace, just put the $1$2 to replace all three blocks with just the first two.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

[NomeN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127947/nomen) has answered correctly, but this answer wouldn't be of much use for beginners like me because we will have another problem to solve and we wouldn't know how to use [RegEx](http://regexr.com/) in there. So I am adding a bit of explanation to this. The answer is

> search: `(\w+\\.someMethod\\(\\))`
>
> replace: `((TypeName)$1)`

Here:

In search:

- First and last `(`, `)` depicts a group in regex
- `\w` depicts words (alphanumeric + underscore)
- `+` depicts one or more (ie one or more of alphanumeric + underscore)
- `.` is a special character which depicts any character (ie `.+` means
  one or more of any character). Because this is a special character
  to depict a `.` we should give an escape character with it, ie `\.`
- `someMethod` is given as it is to be searched.
- The two parenthesis `(`, `)` are given along with escape character
  because they are special character which are used to depict a group
  (we will discuss about group in next point)

In replace:

- It is given `((TypeName)$1)`, here `$1` depicts the
  group.  That is all the characters that are enclosed within the first
  and last parenthesis `(`, `)` in the search field
- Also make sure you have checked the 'Regular expression' option in
  find an replace box

Answer (score 2):

At least at STS (SpringSource Tool Suite) groups are numbered starting form 0, so replace string will be

```
replace: ((TypeName)$0)
```

Comment: That's not true afaik. The $0 represents the whole original search term. In this case I guess that would work coincidentally though.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who needs an explanation and an example of how to use a regxp in Eclipse. Here is my example illustrating the problem.

[image]

I want to rename

```
/download.mp4^lecture_id=271
```

to

```
/271.mp4
```

And there can be multiple of these.

Here is how it should be done.

[image]

Then hit find/replace button