# Eclipse Find/Replace with Regex to comment lines

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have some classes that contains comments like as follow:

```
...
...
...
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void startApplication()
/*     */   {
/*  57 */     initializeFields();
/*  58 */     this.run = true;
/*  59 */     new Thread(this).start();
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void stopApplication() {
/*  63 */     this.run = false;
/*     */   }
/*     */ 
/*     */   public void run()
/*     */   {
...
...
...
```

And i have to clean all `/*  */` strings in my classes. Which regex should i use to do this with using Eclipse's Find/Replace tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Jd-GUi, I've already needed the same regex :)

```
/\*.*?\*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Hit `CTRL+SPACE` on the text boxes it will give you suggestions for regular expressions.
You can fin more details in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `/\*\s+\d*\s+\*/`, or if you also want to strip the space before the code, presuming it's a tab, use `/\*\s+\d*\s+\*/\t`. Optionally change that last tab for a specific number of spaces - if you just use `\s+`, for instance, it will lose your indentation, which you don't want!

Comment: This is JD-GUI's output, the simplest of regex will do :)

Comment: With regex, simple is always better, when the situation allows ;)

Comment: Yes, and in this particular circumstance, since you are running the regex against a generated source code file, there's no other, useful comments you need to worry about.