# Searching for classes which use a method with a specific parameter - in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am maintaining an old code base. One of the classes has this method :

```
someMethod(Param1 a, Param2 b, Param3 c, Param4 d){...};
```

This method is widely  used in many java classes. Like so :

```
foo.someMethod(valueA, null, valueC, null);
```

How can I find which java classes in my code base are using this method where the last parameter is not being passed in as null ?

Comment: This link could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace

Comment: @mmc18 this won't do if you split the method call into two or three lines =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza exactly :( any one has any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can find in eclipse if the method is called with a `null` argument. I would go to the method definition and press Ctrl + Alt + H to find all the places where the method is called, then start doing the refactoring.

Comment: You cannot. You will just have to "View all Usages" and go through each one individually.

Comment: Going via "View all usages" can be impossible. I'm currently having the same task.. refactoring old code.
The method I'm searching for is used 5835 times, but I only care about the ones with a specific parameter...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use Eclipse to refactor the method parameters (right-click -> Refactor -> Change Method Signature..., or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) so that the parameter you are looking for is the first parameter. You then still have to do a text search for the method and value you're looking for, but it might be a bit easier.