# Eclipse, regex search and replace

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have a file which contains text like:
1x
2x
5x
10x
50x
100x
.....

Using Eclipse search and replace with regex, how do I script to have an output like
x1
x2
x5
x10
x50
x100
...

That is to say, search for a regex, break it into fields (\d+x, thus \d+ and 'x' in my case), and reuse the field elements later to resubstitute as 'x'+'\d+'.

I looked at a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace?rq=1) on same lines, but I want to take that a step further.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for

```
(\d+)x
```

and replace with

```
x\1
```

And enable "Regular expressions". It will put the 'x' in front of the number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

search:  `(\d+)(.+)`

replace with : `\2\1`

or `$2$1` whichever eclipse supports