# Exclude Matches which start with '#'

Tags: regex

I am using this simple regex for my plain text files:

```
\([A-Za-z]*\)
```

I get matches like:

`...(test)...`, `...(Next)...`, `...(Warning)...` and so on

Is it possible to exclude matches which start with `#`? For example:

```
 #  Caught Stealing from Something (Warning)   (3300-3599)
```

---

I have tried a lot and came up with this:

```
(?:^\s*?#.*)|(\([A-Za-z0-9\s\-]*\))
```

Now i need to display only the matches of 1st capturing group, but i don't know how. Can someone give a tip?

Comment: Perl regex? Do you have grep? I'd break the problem in two: `grep FILE -Pe "^[^#]" | grep -shoPe "\(\w+\)"`

Comment: Don't know, i am working with eclipse on simple txt files. I think i can't use your solution in eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

This is not as straight-forward as it looks.

Normally you'd use **lookarounds** for something like this, but your case is pretty unorthodox. You want to get non-line related results (as any line can have any number of results) with a line related requirement (the absence of #).

Lookarounds will normally be line-specific and only have one result.

**My solution:**

`\s*?#.*(?:\n|$)|(\([A-Za-z0-9\s\-]*\))`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP6uY5/3)

You won't avoid having your results within capture groups I'm afraid. In this case, all of your results will be $1. The idea is that you describe the possibility of a commented line, and if it's not met, you describe how items you're interested could look. Since the commented line option is first, the items within it won't be tested

I also changed your regex to also contain spaces, dashes and numbers to have more cases of `(content123)` and alike. If you don't want that, discard the changes and use `\s*?#.*(?:\n|$)|(\([A-Za-z]*\))`

There are definitely some other ways to do this, but this is the one i had most success with.

Comment: This is actually pretty nice. Could you just explain what do you need the `|.` for? It seems to me that without it you will make a lot less matches, but still you will have all the matches that contain non-empty value for the $1 group.

Comment: It matches but doesn't capture (because of `?:`), but you're right, you actually don't need it the way I wrote it anymore. I used it to describe the character jumps but the regex tries that on its own because I didn't specify the start or end of the line or string.

Comment: Unhappily it doesn't work and i don't understand what you are saying, i can only build simple regex. Your solution matches also lines which starts with #, but i want completely ignore these lines. I only need matches which have one word in (), like (text)

Comment: Yes, that's intended. You need to use what's called **capture groups** and you need to call them differently, normally with $1. What text redactor/tool are you using? There isn't a solution where just matches will give you the wanted answer.

Comment: ah ok thanks Andris. Iam using eclipse. How would the expression look like with capture groups or isn't it possible with eclipse?

Comment: It is, i'm browsing some SO questions and there are some examples, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1372766/4635642) for instance. So it is really `$1`, but you have to fiddle around and test it a bit to understand how to achieve your goal.

Comment: ok, i understand. I've tested it in eclipse and i can use $1 for the current match, but this doesn't help me. I don't know how to use it for my solution, can you help me please? `(\([A-Za-z]*\))[^\^#]`