# regular expression retrieve a portion of a string that not contain a string

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have some strings like the following:

```
it.mycompany.db.beans.str1.PD_T_CLASS
it.mycompany.db.beans.join.PD_T_CLASS
it.mycompany.db.beans.str2.PD_T_CLASS_1
it.mycompany.db.beans.join.PD_T_CLASS_1
PD_T_CLASS myVar = new PD_T_CLASS();
myVar.setPD_T_CLASS(something);
```

and I want to select "PD_" part to substitute it with "" (the void string) but only inf the entire line does not contain the string ".join."

what I want to achieve is:

```
it.mycompany.db.beans.str1.T_CLASS
it.mycompany.db.beans.join.PD_T_CLASS
it.mycompany.db.beans.str2.T_CLASS_1
it.mycompany.db.beans.join.PD_T_CLASS_1
T_CLASS myVar = new T_CLASS();
myVar.setT_CLASS(something);
```

The substitution is not a problem since I'm using eclipse search tool and will hit replace as soon as it show me the right result.

I have tried:

```
^((?!\.join\.).)*(PD_)*$ // whole string selected 
^((?!\.join\.).)*(\bPD_\b)*$ // whole string selected
```

I start getting frustrated since I've searched a bit around (the ^((?!join bla bla come from those searches)

Can you help me?

Comment: Try [`^(?!.*\.join\.)(.*)PD_` => `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/SG3IHE/3). I understand there is only 1 `PD_` on a line to remove?

Comment: nope ... it select the whole line again :(

Comment: Yes, it does, but replace with `$1`

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace

Comment: 1) there can be multiple occurrence of PD_ in a single line since is a code line and PD_something is a class and have for sure PD_a_field and they are a lot
2) not suere if eclipse search tool can use $1 for substitution ... i'm not vriting code ... i'm substiting portion of code with void string (is for database table name changes)

Comment: @Alex75 OK, try the expression in the answer. If it overmatches, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?!.*\.join\.))(.*?)PD_
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SG3IHE/4)

**Details**:

- `(?m)` - a `Pattern.MULTILINE` inline modifier flag that will force `^` to match the beginning of a line rather than a whole string
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?!.*\.join\.))` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!\A)` - the end of the previous successful match
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?!.*\.join\.)` -  start of a line that has no `.join.` text in it (as the `(?!.*\.join\.)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if it matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) and then `.join.`)
- `(.*?)`  - Capturing group #1 (referred to with the `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than line breaks, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of ...
- `PD_` - a literal `PD_`

The replacement is a `$1` backreference to the first capturing group that will restore any text matched before `PD_`s.