# How to find all instances where function return value is not evaluated in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

Given a function that returns either an object e.g. `String` or `null` - how can I easily find all locations in code where the return value is not being either assigned to a `String` variable (`case1`) or immediately evaluated as part of a condition (`case2`)?

e.g.

```
public String getMessageInLog(String toFind) {
    // return String or null, depending on if found
}

String lineInLog = getMessageInLog("test"); // case1
Assert.assertNotNull(getMessageInLog("test"); // case2
Assert.assertNotNull("Failure error message", getMessageInLog("test"); // case2 (extended example - why searching for " getMessageInLog(" does not work.
getMessageInLog("test") // case3 - what I'm trying to find
```

This type of call is being used thousands of times in tests and I would like to identify where it is being used like in `case3`.

Comment: Only for this specific method called `getMessageInLog`?

Comment: Look through the settings of Eclipse. It may have an option to warn when a return value isn't used. You'll get a lot of irrelevant warnings along with it though.

Comment: @luk2302 For this method (and others overrides of it with more/different parameters). I know I can use the Call Hierarchy view on each but it's very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a regex search [Eclipse, regular expression search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372748/eclipse-regular-expression-search-and-replace) for

```
$\s+getMessageInLog
```

Comment: I suppose I need to expand my example as there is often `Assert.assertNotNull("Error message", getMessageInLog("test"));` which would be picked up with this regex but is actually `case2`

Comment: @ReadyPlayer2 that should not be caught since it does not only have whitespaces in front of the method name.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Eclipse plugin which would be able to

1. find references to methods and classes with [SearchEngine](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fsearch%2FSearchEngine.html).
2. interact with the Java compiler using the [JDT plugin](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_int_core.htm) (Java Development Tooling) to create AST's for the references you found.
3. traverse the AST's a bit to see how the references are used (if condition, right side of assignment or stand-alone statement)